# How to call a function in a widget once Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am displaying this widget right, so now I want to show the teamLogo only the first time I am calling this widget, after that, I do not want to show it.

This is on my animatedCircularProgressBarCard Widget:

```
class AnimatedCircularProgressBarCard extends StatelessWidget {
 final bool showTeamLogo;
  final String? homeTeamLogo;
  final String? awayTeamLogo;
 Widget _teamLogo({required String? logo}) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 28,
      width: 28,
      child: OptimizedImage(
        logo,
        imageWidth: 64,
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    );
  }

//how I am calling it for home and awayTeam
 Expanded(
          flex: (0.10 * 1000).round(),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: showTeamLogo == true
                ? _teamLogo(
                    logo: homeTeamLogo,
                  )
                : const SizedBox(),
          ),
        ),
 Expanded(
          flex: (0.10 * 1000).round(),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: showTeamLogo == true
                ? _teamLogo(
                    logo: awayTeamLogo,
                  )
                : const SizedBox(),
          ),
        ),
```

This is how I am calling this widget

```
class NetballStatsLayouts {
  String netballStatsLayout = '''
    {
      "key": "netball_top_stats",
      "definition": [
      //I only want the showLogo to show here only
        {
        "key": "Centre Pass To Goal Percentage",
        "datapoint": "centrePassToGoalPercentage",
        "widget": "animatedCircularProgressBarCard"
      },
        {
        "key": "Gain To Goal Percentage",
        "datapoint": "gainToGoalPercentage",
        "widget": "animatedCircularProgressBarCard"
      },
```

So, I want when I am calling this animatedCircularProgressBarCard widget the first time, it must show the teamLogo for both homeTeam and awayTeam once and not show the teamLogo again when I call the widget more than once.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you mean "once per lifecycle", that'd be initState.  If you mean "once per application run", that'd be some sort of global state management, or even just a singleton.  If you mean "once per app installation", then that's gonna be something with shared-preferences.